# Symfony2 Gedmo Loggable crashes out on flush call

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, flush

I have a Symfony2 project, and I'm having a problem with Gedmo's Loggable extension.

I have a form which is being constructed and submitted properly, passes validation, yet when the `$EntityManager->flush()` gets called to add the form data to the database (MySQL with Doctrine), I get the following:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Path\To\My\Entity\Class::setAction() 
in /path/to/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/LoggableListener.php line 225

at ErrorHandler->handleFatal() in /path/to/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php line 0
at LoggableListener->createLogEntry() in /path/to/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/LoggableListener.php line 188
at LoggableListener->onFlush() in /path/to/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ContainerAwareEventManager.php line 61
at ContainerAwareEventManager->dispatchEvent() in /path/to/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 306
at UnitOfWork->commit() in /path/to/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 355
at EntityManager->flush() in /Path/To/My/Bundle/Controller.php line 364
at Controller->addEntityAction() in /Path/To/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2891
at ??call_user_func_array() in /Path/To/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2891
at HttpKernel->handleRaw() in /Path/To/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2865
at HttpKernel->handle() in /Path/To/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2994
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() in /Path/To/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2274
at Kernel->handle() in /Path/To/web/app_dev.php line 28
at ??{main}() in /Path/To/web/app_dev.php line 0
```

LoggableListner.php line 188 is:

```
    foreach ($ea->getScheduledObjectInsertions($uow) as $object) {
        $this->createLogEntry(self::ACTION_CREATE, $object, $ea);
    }
```

and the full function surrounding the `foreach` on line 188 is:

```
public function onFlush(EventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $ea = $this->getEventAdapter($eventArgs);
    $om = $ea->getObjectManager();
    $uow = $om->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($ea->getScheduledObjectInsertions($uow) as $object) {
        $this->createLogEntry(self::ACTION_CREATE, $object, $ea);
    }
    foreach ($ea->getScheduledObjectUpdates($uow) as $object) {
        $this->createLogEntry(self::ACTION_UPDATE, $object, $ea);
    }
    foreach ($ea->getScheduledObjectDeletions($uow) as $object) {
        $this->createLogEntry(self::ACTION_REMOVE, $object, $ea);
    }
}
```

LoggableListner.php line 225 is:

```
        /** @var \Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry $logEntry */
        $logEntry = $logEntryMeta->newInstance();
```

My entities have the standard Symfony2 annotations for Loggable, ie:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
* @Gedmo\Loggable(logEntryClass="My\Bundles\ThisBundle\ThisEntity")
*/

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
* @Assert\Length(max=30)
* @Gedmo\Versioned
*/
protected $name;
```

And I have no idea where the `setAction()` call is coming from. There is nothing in my class named "action" and there is no function or method such as `getAction()`, `addAction()`, `removeAction()`, etc. (Nor should there be from my understanding.)

Thanks for any insight and assistance!

Comment: Will even take troubleshooting advice if anyone has any!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after carefully walking the stack trace and looking at the Loggable functions, it dawned on me that the error was clearly from loggable attempting to implement a function from one of my entities, which told me that somewhere I had a class somewhere it shouldn't be (as I wanted Loggable to use its own classes and functions, not mine).

I therefore changed

```
/**
* @Gedmo\Loggable(logEntryClass="My\Bundles\ThisBundle\ThisEntity")
*/
```

to just

```
/**
* @Gedmo\Loggable
*/
```

which meant it used its own class to carry out the logging and - voila. No more error.